# Is the set of “Pythagorean” square roots dense in $\left[0, \infty\right)$?

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

I was thinking about proofs of the fact that square roots exist and ended up wondering if
the set of numbers of the form  $\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}+ \dfrac{c^2}{d^2}}$ with $a, b, c, d \in\Bbb N$ is a dense subset of $\left[0, \infty\right)$.

I have no idea how to go about determining this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any $x\in [0,\infty)$ and any $\epsilon>0$, we have a rational $\frac ab$ within $\frac\epsilon2$ of $x$.  Also we may let $c=1$ and pick $d$ large enough that $\frac ab$ and $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{c^2}{d^2}}$ are within $\frac\epsilon2$ of each other.  Then we have $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{c^2}{d^2}}$ within $\epsilon$ of $x$.

---

To see that for for sufficiently large $d$, $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{1}{d^2}}$ can be arbitrarily close to $\frac ab$, note that:$$\left(
\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{1}{d^2}}-\frac ab\right)
\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{1}{d^2}}+\frac ab\right)=\frac 1{d^2}
$$

As $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{1}{d^2}}+\frac ab\right)>\frac{2a}b,$$
we have $$0<\left(
\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+ \frac{1}{d^2}}-\frac ab\right)<\frac b{2ad^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your proof.  Is there a way to show $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b} + \frac{1}{d^2}}$ are close to each other without assuming continuity of the square root function?

Comment: @skh Edited to show that.